# to display message based on start date and stop date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to retrieve a particular message based on start date and stop date.
the table consists of rows of messages each assigned for particular start date and stop date. the sql should compare the current date with start date and stop date and if its matches  start date it should display only that particular message. that message should not be displayed when current date exceeds stop date

Comment: Could you provide a data table schema

Answer (score 3):

Assuming table

```
Column Name | Type
StartDate   | DateTime
StopDate    | DateTime
Message     | no matter
```

SQL:

```
-- cache to optimize performance
DECLARE @currentDate DateTime
SET @currentDate = GETDATE()


SELECT message 
FROM dataTable
WHERE @currentDate < StopDate AND @currentDate = StartDate
```

Comment: I still dont see the message displayed yet

Comment: my column are message, startdate, stopdate and currentdate. your code just displays the column name message but not the particular message

Comment: Why you need column currentDate? Anyway if you have such column then change in WHERE clause '@currentDate' to 'currentdate'

Comment: Can't believe that "SELECT message .. " outputs "message" string itself, can you show particular query which you are using

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
declare @date datetime
select @date = getdate()
declare @table table (FromDate datetime, ToDate datetime, mesg varchar(50))


insert @table values('2008','12-31-2010', 'once')
insert @table values('01-01-2011','12-31-2011', 'this year')
insert @table values('01-01-2012','12-31-2015', 'future')

select mesg from @table where @date between FromDate and ToDate
```